# c++ read unknow amount of data from socket

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, bytestream

I wrote a simple `tcp/ip` connection `client-server` in `c++`.

This is the part of the server that handles the connection

```
int sockfd, newsockfd;
socklen_t clilen;
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
int n = 0;

sockfd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
if(sockfd < 0){
    cout << "Error opening socket" << endl;
    exit(1);
}

bzero((char*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

if(bind(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr))<0){
    cout << "Error binding" << endl;
    exit(1);
}

listen(sockfd,1);
clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);

newsockfd = accept(sockfd,(struct  sockaddr *)&cli_addr, &clilen );

if(newsockfd < 0){
    cout << "Error accepting" << endl;
    exit(1);
}

bzero(bytes,size_tot);
uint64_t total_bytes_read = 0;
uint64_t total_bytes_to_read = size_tot;
while(total_bytes_read < total_bytes_to_read){
    int bytes_read = read(newsockfd,bytes + total_bytes_read,total_bytes_to_read - total_bytes_read);
    if(bytes_read == -1){
        cout << "error reading "<< endl;
        n = -1;
        break;
    }
    total_bytes_read += bytes_read;
}
```

but this works if I know the total amount of bytes to be read. What if the total amount of data to be read is unknown? How I can modify this piece of code?

Comment: It looks like this question is ambiguous and that's leading to conflicting answers. It's not clear what you want to actually read. Do you want to read all the bytes until the other side closes the connection? Or what?

Comment: I believe, the question is perfectly clear, and OP is asking how to generally deal with the case when the size of the transmission is not known beforehand.

Comment: Then my answer was precisely correct. You just call `read` without a loop that waits for some particular number of bytes. (His question was about how to modify low-level receiving code, not how to write high-level protocol code.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked how to fix your low-level receiving code. That's simple -- just call `read` once and don't use a `while` loop. The call to `read` will return as soon as at least one byte of data can be read. For the number of bytes to read, just pass in the size of your buffer (or the space left in it if there's already some leftover in it from a prior call).

You will also need high-level protocol code, just as you do if you know the number of bytes. That code will probably need to be a bit different. If the chunk of bytes you got includes your stop indication, then process all the bytes up to the stop indication and keep the extra in the buffer for next time. If not, just call `read` again and get a bunch more bytes.

Your protocol handling code should look sort of like this:

1. Call `read` and add however many bytes you got to the buffer. (Handle an error or normal close here.)
2. If the data in the buffer does not include the stop indication, go to step 1.
3. Process all the bytes up to the stop indication.
4. Remove the processed bytes from the buffer, leaving any unprocessed bytes.
5. Go to step 2.

Also, the code you gave in the question will spin forever if the other side closes the connection. In this case, `read` will return zero and you will never be able to read any more data from the connection. You should break out of the loop if `read` returns zero.

Comment: `read` is not guaranteed to return all the data - only calling it once is not a complete solution.

Comment: @user2864740 I don't know what you mean by "all the data". All *what* data?

Comment: @David, if it won't be you, I'd downvote immediately. For you, I'd give you a second chance to explain yourself.

Comment: the "read" function does not read all data, I send something like 1gigabits and if I do not put the read inside a while loop it reads only just "few" bytes

Comment: @J.kol That's what you asked how to do. You asked how to read just a few bytes in a case where you don't know how many you want. Or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: @David, I believe, you did.

Comment: @J.kol All *what* bytes? All the bytes until the other side closes the connection?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz . All bytes until a specific byte that says "stop"

Comment: @J.kol Then my answer is correct. I added some extra information to help clarify.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, get rid of all `bzero` calls. I do not know why this keeps creeping into good people's code. There is zero, nada, nicht need for this.

Second of all, you'd need to either somehow communicate the size of transmission beforehand - for example, HTTP 1.1 provides for this information in the header - or simply state that connection is closed once all the data has been transferred - this would be HTTP 1.0 model.

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to address the question the OP asked. He asked how to call `read` when he doesn't know how many bytes he needs to read.

Comment: @David, NO. You misunderstood the question, and now you are dowvoting me for the thing I understood properly.

Comment: He asked how to modify his code to handle the case where he doesn't know how many bytes he wants to read. That is very simple -- just don't keep looping until you get some particular number of bytes.